# Redis plugin blocking in Publish/Subscribe

Tags: scala, playframework, redis, publish-subscribe, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to connect to Redis for Publish-Subscribe using the [Typesafe Redis Play plugin](https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/redis).

I have the following test scenario, consisting of an actor that generates messages every second:

```
  // Initialization happens in Application.scala,
  private lazy val fakeStreamActor = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[FakeStreamActor])

  val actorPut = Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(
    Duration(1000, MILLISECONDS),
    Duration(1000, MILLISECONDS),
    fakeStreamActor,
    Put("This is a sample message"))
```

The actor source:

```
class FakeStreamActor extends Actor {
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(1, SECONDS)

  val CHANNEL = "channel1"
  val plugin = Play.application.plugin(classOf[RedisPlugin]).get
  val listener = new MyListener()

  val pool = plugin.sedisPool

  pool.withJedisClient{ client =>
    client.subscribe(listener, CHANNEL)
  }

  def receive = {

    case Put(msg: String) => {
      //send data to Redis
      Logger.info("Push %s".format(msg))
      pool.withJedisClient { client =>
        client.publish(CHANNEL, msg)
      }

    }
  }
}

/** Messages */
case class Put(msg: String)
```

And a subscribe listener:

```
case class MyListener() extends JedisPubSub {
  def onMessage(channel: String, message: String): Unit = {
    Logger.info("onMessage[%s, %s]".format(channel, message))
  }

  def onSubscribe(channel: String, subscribedChannels: Int): Unit = {
    Logger.info("onSubscribe[%s, %d]".format(channel, subscribedChannels))
  }

  def onUnsubscribe(channel: String, subscribedChannels: Int): Unit = {
    Logger.info("onUnsubscribe[%s, %d]".format(channel, subscribedChannels))
  }

  def onPSubscribe(pattern: String, subscribedChannels: Int): Unit = {
    Logger.info("onPSubscribe[%s, %d]".format(pattern, subscribedChannels))
  }

  def onPUnsubscribe(pattern: String, subscribedChannels: Int): Unit = {
    Logger.info("onPUnsubscribe[%s, %d]".format(pattern, subscribedChannels))
  }

  def onPMessage(pattern: String, channel: String, message: String): Unit = {
    Logger.info("onPMessage[%s, %s, %s]".format(pattern, channel, message))
  }
}
```

Now, ideally I should be subscribing to the defined channel and seeing in the logs how the **Listener** is processing the received messages every second. But that doesn't happen, as the act of subscribing locks the thread.

My question is:

There is any way to take advantage of Play asynchronous nature to have non-blocking subscription?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup. This is how I do it in Global.scala:

```
Akka.future { 
  val j = new RedisPlugin(app).jedisPool.getResource
  j.subscribe(PubSub, "*")
}
```

I had trouble instantiating the plugin, but you'd essentially put the withJedisClient bit inside of the future block.

Thanks for showing me how to instantiate the plugin in scala!

Comment: no, thanks to you for showing me the Future part, I completely forgot about it :D